# for flutter_charts package is there an API reference?

Tags: flutter

the API Docs link on this page https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/charts_flutter

doesn't go to an API documentation. There are examples, but it would make it easier to use if there were a regular API doc. Does one exist somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right here: https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/charts_flutter/latest/flutter/flutter-library.html. You probably missed clicking 'flutter' under the libraries header, which admittedly is a little confusing.